# jQuery class selector not working in this function

Tags: jquery, selector

This is my code:

```
$('.clicktotriggerajax').live('change', function(){
    history.pushState({}, '', this.href);
    popstate(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

I must use a `class` in this function instead of an `id` because I am attaching it to multiple elements.  However, the problem that I am facing is that this function does not function correctly when using the class `.clicktotriggerajax`.  I use this function to asynchronously load my pages and it seems as if the `return false` is not working because it is taking the direct path of the url instead of executing the rest of the script I have, which I can show if you guys need to see it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why on the change event? isn't click more appropriated? also this in that context refers to the dom object

Comment: The html is on this page, http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/loadlistensong.php which I get from a javascript function and load onto /listen.php

Comment: I also tried .click() but neither worked, so I didn't know which one I should be using.

Comment: That's too much code to dig through.  Ideally, you would post the code that is relevant to reproducing your issue within the question itself.

Comment: If you want something to happen on "click" you should use the "click" event handler; the problem is probably elsewhere. I can't see the relation of the page you linked to your actual question (i.e.: no buttons to click, no ajax, lot of code, no time)

Answer (score 0):

Live event handlers trigger once the event propagates to the Document, so anything lower in the chain will have already triggered. I imagine this is what's happening.  See http://api.jquery.com/live/

You say it's because you are using a class.  If you use an id does it work? I would expect it to fail in both cases.

I've had cases where I had to special-case logic for handling other events to exclude events already handled by one of my live handlers. (E.g. the live handler removes something from the DOM, so the click handler makes sure it's still in the DOM before processing further.)  It's a case-by-case thing, I don't know a global fix for this issue.

I don't have a reasonable guess as to what your code is doing with a 'change' event on a class that says "click" in it either.  What are you trying to stop? You wouldn't be trying to stop the default action on a button or a hyperlink with a "change" event, would you?  Maybe you mean "click" event?

Comment: I also tried the click event but that did not work.  I only used the change event to try it out because I thought it could work, but it did not.